# How to send alerts in TFS whenever there's a change in the work item of the creator

Tags: tfs-2015

Is there a way in TFS that will notify only the creator of the ticket whenever there's an update made in the work item he/she created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way.

1. Open the workitem in TFS then click on the email button from the menu bar.
   [image]
2. Add the email address of the creator of the workitem in the “To” field; the message to the creator of the ticket in the “Note” field; and click “Send” button and that's it.
   [image]

Comment: That's sending the email manually, but not the really notification/alert as you requested whenever there's an update made in the work item he/she created.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the personal alerts, that means everyone need to set the alert for himself/herself. See [Set alerts just for yourself](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/work/track/alerts-and-notifications#set-alerts-just-for-yourself) for details.

For TFS 2015, just create a new alert : `A change is made to a work item that I created`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andy. Is there a way that I would only need to configure this in TFS and this settings should automatically be reflected to the alerts of all TFS users?

Comment: @Artline157 No, everyone need to set the alert separately. Team alert will be reflect all TFS team users, but all the team member will receive the alerts. So, the only way to achieve that is asking each member to create the alert for themselves.

Comment: All right. I guess that's another limitation of TFS that one user cannot configure the same alert system that would reflect to all users. Thanks Andy!